# Identify iframe with specific string in src

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

The target webpage sometimes contains a single embedded iframe video. I wish to open those specific videos in the current tab.

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" src="https://streamview.com/v/wkx5ntgwdv5b"></iframe>
```

My code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var openontaB = document.querySelector('iframe').src;
    window.location.href = openontaB;
})();
```

The issue is that the above code does not open the correct iframe src. How would I make it work/match only for an iframe that contains the string [streamview.com](https://streamview.com/)?

​Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: var links = document.getElementById("iframe");  
  
for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {  
  var link = links[i];  
  if (link.href.indexOf("streamview.com") !== -1) {  
    (function() {  
    'use strict';  
  
    var openontaB = document.querySelector('iframe').src;  
    window.location.href = openontaB;  
})();  
  }  
}  

still not working

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting one as the "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer). Doing that will acknowledge the answer and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community. You receive points each time you close out a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```js
// look for an iframe with 'streamview.com' in its src
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="streamview.com"]');
// if found, set location
iframe && (location.href = iframe.src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try (untested):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    const allIF = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

    allIF.forEach( frm => {
        const openontaB = frm.src;
        if (openontaB.includes('streamview.com')){
            window.location.href = openontaB;
        }
    });
})();
```